Who can explain this weird inference in TypeScript?
I'm sure this is the expected behaviour but it looks counter-intuitive for me. Given the following snippet, why is item inferred as { a: number } instead of { b: number }? I was expecting a kind of overriding in Options & { activities: Array<{ b: number }>}.

I've discovered that replacing options param type by Omit<Options, 'activities'> & { activities: Array<{ b: number }> } solves the problem, but I would like to understand why TS works this way to get the need of an Omit<>.
Here's the code so you can copy-paste:
type Activity = { a: number };
type Options = { activities: Activity[] }

const fun = (options: Options & { activities: Array<{ b: number }> }) => {
    return options.activities.map(item => item.b)
}

I was expecting an overriding of activities property so it gets { b: number }[] type.

maybe you meant to do equivalent?  type Options = { activities: Activity & { b: number } }

@cmgchess not really. I actually want an override. This is a very simple example so I could do it better :-), but this illustrates the behaviour of a much complex code. So I find it easier to understand.

Looks like the error message exists only in an image. Screenshots of IDEs are unfortunately not appropriate here. Please replace images of code/logs/errors/tooltips with plaintext versions.

(see prev comment) • The canonical answer is ms/TS#41874. Intersections of methods produce overloads, so there are two map call signatures and you're hitting the one you don't want. Intersections of arrays are weird and it's not clear how to fix it. If you want (A & B)[] then write that instead. Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write an a; if not, what am I missing?
